# HTML5 Select Multiple Values to Array

Tags: javascript, html, css

We would like to use HTML5 `select` input to return an array of values, for example this select input

```
<select id="fruits" multiple>
   <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
   <option value="apples" selected>Apples</option>
   <option value="grapes" selected>Grapes</option>
</select>
```

When we are trying to get the value using

```
fruits = fruits.value // this produces only 'apples'
```

Why Only Apples? How can we get the value from the select input to return an **array** of fruits (values) ?

Thanks!

btw - this can be seen in the following fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/eaby035z/

### Also, How can we do this the other way around?!

```
var favorites = ['apples','oranges'];
fruits.value = favorites // doesn't work...
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map.call(element.selectedOptions, elm => elm.value)`

Comment: @haim770 can you write also how to set? thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be :

At first you need to select all the options and iterate through them.

options would be a HTMLCollection and you can iterate using a for loop ( among others ) and inside that for loop you can get the values. See below

TO get them inside an array just push them in an empty array.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select")
const options = select.options
const fruits = [];
for ( let i=0; i< options.length; i++) {
 fruits.push(options[i].value)
}
console.log(fruits)
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple>
   <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
   <option value="apples" selected>Apples</option>
   <option value="grapes" selected>Grapes</option>
</select>
```

One other solution would be to use `map` array method on the options HTML collection. map returns an array. ( just like haim770 mentioned in the comment to your question )

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select")
const options = select.options
fruitArray = Array.prototype.map.call(options, option => option.value )

console.log(fruitArray)
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple>
   <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
   <option value="apples" selected>Apples</option>
   <option value="grapes" selected>Grapes</option>
</select>
```

After your EDIT to the question asking how to set some values to the options

```js
const favorites = ['value1','value2', 'value3'];
const select = document.getElementById("select")
const options = select.options
for ( let i=0; i< options.length; i++) {
 options[i].value = favorites[i]
  options[i].innerText = favorites[i]
}
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple>
   <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
   <option value="apples" selected>Apples</option>
   <option value="grapes" selected>Grapes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, can you elaborate on how to do this the other way around?

Comment: well just like haim770 said in his comment. i don't want to take that away from him and write it in my own answer :) but if a working example helps you. I will edit my answer. And also, you want to select the options that have the selected attribute? or all the options ? Added the solution with `map`

Comment: @levi edited with solution to add value and text to the options from an array . Careful that the array of new values should have the same length as the existing options collection.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it using JQUERY. Hope it will Help

```js
var selectedOptions = $("#select").val();
console.log(selectedOptions);

function onSelectChange(){
  var selectedOptions = $("#select").val();
  console.log(selectedOptions);
}

var setValue = ["apples","mango"];
function setOptions(){
  $("#select option").prop("selected", false);
  for(var i=0;i<setValue.length;i++){
    $("#select option[value='" + setValue[i] + "']").prop("selected", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" multiple onChange="onSelectChange()">
   <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
   <option value="apples" selected>Apples</option>
   <option value="grapes" selected>Grapes</option>
   <option value="mango" >mango</option>
</select>

<button onClick="setOptions()" >Set Programatically</button>
```

Comment: Why use jQuery when you can solve it with javaScript ?

Comment: @MihaiT yes we can solve it with javascript no issues. If already there is jquery in your project it will be much easier than javascript. or else we can solve it with JS

Comment: as the OP didn't tag jQuery in his question. And he didn't say anything about jQuery. I assume he doesn't have jQuery in his project.

Comment: @MihaiT Okay no issue. It's just one of my solution. let him try which is better for him. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the options of select and get all the option where selected is true.

```js
const select = document.getElementById("select")
const options = select.options
const fruits = [];
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  if (options[i].selected == true) {
    console.log(options[i].value)
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple>
  <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
  <option value="apples" selected>Apples</option>
  <option value="grapes" selected>Grapes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how is this any different than my answer ? :) just copy-paste and adding the selected condition is not an answer :)